# React Native Facebook login error 1349003 on iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I have a bug on Facebook login for iOS only

#### Environment

Output from `react-native info`:

```
Environment:
  OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.1
  Node: 8.9.1
  Yarn: 1.3.2
  npm: 5.5.1
  Watchman: 4.9.0
  Xcode: Xcode 9.1 Build version 9B55
  Android Studio: 3.0 AI-171.4408382

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: 16.0.0-alpha.12 => 16.0.0-alpha.12
  react-native: ^0.48.2 => 0.48.4
```

`react-native-fbsdk@0.6.3`

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. Start react-native, open iOS app
2. Login with Facebook
3. Authenticate with Facebook & approve permissions
4. Encounter error (please refer to below attached image & logs)

#### Expected Behavior

Successfully get `access_token` from Facebook

#### Actual Behavior

Screenshot:

[image: React Native Facebook login error 1349003 on iOS]

This is the verbose log outputted:

```
{
  framesToPop: 1,
  code: 'FacebookSDK',
  nativeStackIOS: [
    '0   WeFit-DEV                           0x000000010f6122e6 RCTJSErrorFromCodeMessageAndNSError + 134',
    '1   WeFit-DEV                           0x000000010f5954b8 __41-[RCTModuleMethod processMethodSignature]_block_invoke_2.216 + 184',
    '2   WeFit-DEV                           0x000000010f8e8c77 __71-[RCTFBSDKLoginManager _loginWithPermissions:resolver:rejecter:isRead:]_block_invoke + 135',
    '3   WeFit-DEV                           0x000000010f93b445 -[FBSDKLoginManager invokeHandler:error:] + 158',
    '4   WeFit-DEV                           0x000000010f93ae15 -[FBSDKLoginManager completeAuthentication:expectChallenge:] + 446',
    '5   WeFit-DEV                           0x000000010f937d6b -[FBSDKLoginURLCompleter completeLogIn:withHandler:] + 369',
    '6   WeFit-DEV                           0x000000010f93cef1 -[FBSDKLoginManager(Native) application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:] + 400',
    '7   WeFit-DEV                           0x000000010f90738f __77-[FBSDKApplicationDelegate application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:]_block_invoke + 71',
    '8   UIKit                               0x0000000115b40932 -[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 1346',
    '9   UIKit                               0x0000000115dc519a -[_UICurrentContextPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 44',
    '10  UIKit                               0x0000000115b447b5 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke_2 + 183',
    '11  UIKit                               0x000000011672be89 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 102',
    '12  UIKit                               0x0000000115b3d6be -[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:] + 251',
    '13  UIKit                               0x0000000115b3d335 -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 1397',
    '14  UIKit                               0x0000000115b3f9cc -[UITransitionView _transitionDidStop:finished:] + 104',
    '15  UIKit                               0x0000000115a6299d -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 354',
    '16  UIKit                               0x0000000115a62fde -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 293',
    '17  UIKit                               0x0000000115a63092 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 473',
    '18  QuartzCore                          0x0000000115564a2b _ZN2CA5Layer23run_animation_callbacksEPv + 323',
    '19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000117e4c2b5 _dispatch_client_callout + 8',
    '20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000117e56496 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1260',
    '21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110324ee9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9',
    '22  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001102e9592 __CFRunLoopRun + 2402',
    '23  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001102e89b9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409',
    '24  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000118d1a9c6 GSEventRunModal + 62',
    '25  UIKit                               0x00000001159cc5e8 UIApplicationMain + 159',
    '26  WeFit-DEV                           0x000000010f3cddcf main + 111',
    '27  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000117ec0d81 start + 1',
    '28  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1'
  ],
  domain: 'com.facebook.sdk.core',
  userInfo: {
    'com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey': 0,
    'com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey': 'Login Error: There is an error in logging you into this application. Please try again later.',
    'com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode': '1349003'
  }
}
```

Unfortunately there's no lucks searching either `FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey` or `FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode`. This bug seems to be appeared on iOS only & recently (our Android app still work fine)

Anyone face this recently?

Thanks

Comment: this error  is The Graph API error code , try to login some other account and see if u faced error

Comment: @Sport all accounts logging in with our iOS app face the same error. The weird thing is Android users don't

Answer (score 0):

Today I got the same problem. It seems that there's some breakdown on the FB side. Here is a topic on FB help page:
https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=509025313233

Comment: What if that link broken/deprecated and just shows the fb business home page?